# Create a Like counter not based on DB

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, counter

I'm not good in coding, but my boss asked me to do a Like counter on a locked web site.

Now, my counter isn't working. It stays ad 0 value.

I tried to study by my self but I've seen that I should create a database table.

I'm asking for help because I read that it could be possible to do the same thing using Cookies, but I don't understand how.

The page is only in html code.

Can anyone help me?

Here's my actual code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clicks = 0;
  function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
</script>
<button
  type="button"
  onClick="onClick()"
  style="
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: solid 1px #c70039;
    background: #c70039;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
  "
>
  <img src="URL" width="35" height="35" alt="" />
</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried your code in JSfiddle it does increment click count

Comment: Using cookies only works for one user, so people will only see how many times they have liked the post, not how many times everyone has liked the post. You may want to reconsider your solution, you will have to save data to some place like a database

Comment: You can use files on the server instead of a database, if your script has sufficient privileges. But then you can as well use a database that uses a single file, such as SQLite - without the need to install some larger database management system such as MySQL.